# .htaccess rule for html5 and http authorization

Tags: php, angularjs, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)       /index.php/#/$1


</IfModule>
```

My intention is to support HTML5 mode for a AngularJS app that I am working on. This works fine and my URL redirections work as expected with the necessary changes in my AngularJS app.

However, I also wish to add the rewrite rule below to the .htaccess so that HTTP_AUTHORIZATION variable can be accessed in my PHP scripts.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]
```

How can I specify both these rules in the .htaccess file?
Adding the second `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` related line in the end of the `<IfModule>` section, breaks PHP from getting access to the Authorization headers from the PHP calls.

I am new to .htaccess and any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

So I figured this out..
The correct way to do this is..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*)       /index.php/#/$1
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},last]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sharath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28166007/5411817)  did not work for me.
I did:

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

and then found that the Bearer Token was hiding in :

```
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
```